# Surreal DB REST API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, surrealdb

How can I handle CORS using surrealDB's API on client-side? Here's my request:
`method: 'POST', headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'NS': 'test', 'DB': 'test' }, body: ('SELECT * FROM users)}`
and this is the error when I send it to server: `Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/sql' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field ns is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

I tried on Postman and ThunderClient (a VsCode extension) and it works, but in client-code I get that error. I also check the official docs and I did not found any solution.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.